# Code that reads the given log file, processes its content, and provides a summary of the logs?

Tags: php

I have program.log file and it is given as;

```
2016-12-12 this is a log line 1 [warning]

2016-12-12 this is a log line 2 [warning]

2016-12-12 this is a log line 3 [error]

2016-12-13 this is a log line 4 [error]

2016-12-14 this is a log line 5 [error]

2016-12-14 this is a log line 6 [warning]
```

I'm not able to write code in PHP that reads this file and process it's content and provides the summary of the logs.
The final output is known but I am unable to do this manually.

The final output looks like

```
2016-12-12 warning:2 error: 1

2016-12-13 warning:0 error: 1

2016-12-14 warning:1 error: 1
```

Comment: why tag python and github?

Comment: Sry for this mistake. I fix this.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Have you even attempted to write this program?

Comment: no, I've not try to solve because i know i can't solve this so i ask to you gus.

Comment: Would you guys help me to solve this issue quickly??

Answer (score 0):

Arent you asking for the solution? Still this will work for you using rejex and some array.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Vaibs
 * Date: 22-07-2017
 * Time: 21:52
 */
$logCurrentDate = null;
$logPrevDate = null;
$report = array();


if ($file = fopen("a.log", "r")) {
    $logTypeErrorCount = 0;
    $logTypeWarningCount = 0;
    $isLogError = false;
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        $a = array();
        preg_match_all("~^\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2}+ (this is a log line)+ (\d+)+ \[(.*)\]~", $line, $a);
        $logCurrentDate = substr($a[0][0], 0, 10);
        $logTypeCurrent = $a[3][0];
        $isLogError = ($logTypeCurrent == "error") ? true : false;

        if ($logCurrentDate != $logPrevDate) {
            $report[$logCurrentDate] = array("Warning" => $logTypeWarningCount = $isLogError ? 0 : 1, "Error" => $logTypeError = $logTypeErrorCount = $isLogError ? 1 : 0);

        } else {
            if ($isLogError) {
                $logTypeErrorCount = $logTypeErrorCount + 1;
            } else {
                $logTypeWarningCount = $logTypeWarningCount + 1;
            }
            $report[$logCurrentDate]['Warning'] = $logTypeWarningCount;
            $report[$logCurrentDate]['Error'] = $logTypeErrorCount;
        }
        $logPrevDate = $logCurrentDate;
    }
    //  print_r($report);

    foreach ($report as $x => $x_value) {
        echo $x . '  warning: ' . $x_value['Warning'] . '  error: ' . $x_value['Error'] . PHP_EOL;
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

a.log : your log file

```
2016-12-12 this is a log line 1 [warning]
2016-12-12 this is a log line 2 [warning]
2016-12-12 this is a log line 3 [error]
2016-12-13 this is a log line 4 [error]
2016-12-14 this is a log line 5 [error]
2016-12-14 this is a log line 6 [warning]
```